# I have a question about setup LeGO-LOAM

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when building the source, running catkin_make produces the following error. what is the solution?

Ubuntu 18.04
Melodic
https://jdh1005a.tistory.com/22

```
xaviernx@xaviernx-desktop:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/melodic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/melodic
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found suitable version "2.7.17", minimum required is "2") 
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python2
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gtests will be built
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/googletest': gmock will be built
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2 (found version "2.7.17") 
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.29
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 9 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - cloud_msgs
-- ~~  - velodyne (metapackage)
-- ~~  - velodyne_msgs
-- ~~  - loam_velodyne
-- ~~  - lego_loam
-- ~~  - velodyne_driver
-- ~~  - velodyne_laserscan
-- ~~  - velodyne_pcl
-- ~~  - velodyne_pointcloud
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'cloud_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(LeGO-LOAM/cloud_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- cloud_msgs: 1 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'velodyne'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(velodyne/velodyne)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'velodyne_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(velodyne/velodyne_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- velodyne_msgs: 2 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'loam_velodyne'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(loam_velodyne)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- Boost version: 1.65.1
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
--   thread
--   date_time
--   iostreams
--   serialization
--   chrono
--   atomic
--   regex
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing: ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing: DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** io features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing: _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** io features related to dssdk will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to pcap will be disabled
** WARNING ** io features related to png will be disabled
-- The imported target "vtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets" references the file
   "/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvtkRenderingPythonTkWidgets.so"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

-- The imported target "vtk" references the file
   "/usr/bin/vtk"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   "/usr/lib/cmake/vtk-6.3/VTKTargets.cmake"
but not all the files it references.

** WARNING ** io features related to libusb-1.0 will be disabled
-- Could NOT find ensenso (missing: ENSENSO_LIBRARY ENSENSO_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to ensenso will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DAVIDSDK (missing: DAVIDSDK_LIBRARY DAVIDSDK_INCLUDE_DIR) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to davidSDK will be disabled
-- Could NOT find DSSDK (missing: _DSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to dssdk will be disabled
-- Could NOT find RSSDK (missing: _RSSDK_LIBRARIES) 
** WARNING ** visualization features related to rssdk will be disabled
-- looking for PCL_COMMON
-- looking for PCL_OCTREE
-- looking for PCL_IO
-- looking for PCL_KDTREE
-- looking for PCL_SEARCH
-- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
-- looking for PCL_FILTERS
-- looking for PCL_2D
-- looking for PCL_GEOMETRY
-- looking for PCL_FEATURES
-- looking for PCL_ML
-- looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
-- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
-- looking for PCL_SURFACE
-- looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
-- looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
-- looking for PCL_TRACKING
-- looking for PCL_RECOGNITION
-- looking for PCL_STEREO
-- looking for PCL_APPS
-- looking for PCL_IN_HAND_SCANNER
-- looking for PCL_MODELER
-- looking for PCL_POINT_CLOUD_EDITOR
-- looking for PCL_OUTOFCORE
-- looking for PCL_PEOPLE
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'lego_loam'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(LeGO-LOAM/LeGO-LOAM)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/cv_bridge/cmake/cv_bridgeConfig.cmake:113 (message):
  Project 'cv_bridge' specifies '/usr/include/opencv' as an include dir,
  which is not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '${{prefix}}//usr/include/opencv'.  Check the issue tracker
  'https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/issues' and consider
  creating a ticket if the problem has not been reported yet.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package)
  LeGO-LOAM/LeGO-LOAM/CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/xaviernx/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/399541/i-have-a-question-about-setup-lego-loam/) by [Meerkat25](https://answers.ros.org/users/103062/meerkat25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It can't find opencv on your system, either it's not installed or installed somewhere else. Have you installed opencv?

It could be that you've installed a different version of opencv (when I check the path `/usr/include/opencv` on my pc I find `usr/include/opencv4` for instance). If that's the case you'll need to update the CMake file to build against the version of opencv you've got installed.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1